# What does "Only it wasn't" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Dune* (2021), Paul had a hallucination after inhaling spice:

> Paul: It's confusing. I thought I saw my death, **only it wasn't**.

What does "Only it wasn't" mean?

Comment: "Only" is used as "however" in this context.

Comment: *only* "conjunction, informal :  except that; but for the fact that."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means *I thought I saw my death, but it wasn't actually my death that I saw.*